# How to group a query to match one or more words in elasticsearch?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have this query

```
    {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": "LAS VEGAS, HENDERSON",
              "fields": ["city"]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

this returns:

```
"city": "LAS VEGAS",
"city": "LAS CRUCES",
"city": "HENDERSON",
```

Note the `LAS CRUCES` result. I don't want it.

One way would be to have it written like this:

```
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "match": {
              "city": {
                "query": "LAS VEGAS",
                "operator": "and"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "city": {
                "query": "HENDERSON",
                "operator": "and"
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

But I prefer the first approach, if it can be done.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `query_string` query as shown below:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "fields" : ["city"],
            "query" : "\"LAS VEGAS\" OR \"HENDERSON\""
        }
    }
}
```

You need to enclose the values in quotes to search for exact phrase.

If you are using `city` field for searching exact matches then you should consider changing it's mapping type from `text` to `keyword`. It will fetch you good performance.

If your `city` field is of type `keyword` then you can achieve the same results using `terms query` as shown below:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "terms" : { "city" : ["LAS VEGAS", "HENDERSON"]}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[multi_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) accepts the `operator` flag, which can be set to `or`.

```
   {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": "LAS VEGAS, HENDERSON",
              "fields": ["city"],
              "operator": "or"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: nope. still same results  `(+first_name:will +first_name:smith) 
 | (+last_name:will  +last_name:smith)`